# How to read maximum input

Tags: power-meter

[image]

This is **Carlo Gavazzi Power Analyzer**, the sticker says

**Input 3x380(660)V**

Does it means that the maximum input voltage per line must be 380V or 660V?

Comment: Strange way to write a range.

Comment: Ask them, they also have 5(6)A what in the world is that supposed to mean? It means they know how to write unintelligible ratings.

Comment: Do you have a manual for this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "range code" of your product is "AV5", it means that your product can handle from 380V to 660V on its 3 inputs (-> tri-phase). The "D" letter also means that you must supply this power analyzer with 230VAC.

**UPDATE :** When I say :

> from 380V to 660V

I mean 380V to 660V **AC Three-phased**.

**Source :**
[Datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/13e1/0900766b813e19e3.pdf)